# Implementing singleton with vanilla JavaScript in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project ( vanilla web application ) where I serve html files from the **backend** using nodejs router:

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(views_dir + "index.html");
});

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(views_dir + "login.html");
});
```

and serve the js files as static  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend')));` where the `/frontend` folder holds all the frontend files ( including the html files ).

Now, I have a file called `model.js` ( in **frontend** folder ) where I'm trying to implement a singleton that will hold data that is common to all pages ( such as if the user is currently logged or not ):

```js
const Model = (function () {
    let instance;

    function init() { 

        let isLogged = false;

        return {
            getIsLogged: function () {
                return isLogged;
            },
            setIsLogged: function (l) {
                isLogged = l;
            }
        }
    }
    return { 
        getInstance: function () {
            if (! instance) {
                instance = init();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
})();
```

**But when a user being redirected, seems like the model.js being imported all over again from the backend side, overriding all changes to the model from the previous page.**
( Say we change the isLogged variable in the model to true when a user logged in, and redirecting to '/', the model being refreshed and overwritten )

Is there even a way to implement such a requirement with just JavaScript ?

I think the problem is with `res.sendFile(views_dir + "index.html");` which refreshes the application to a new state and doesn't saves the previous state of the js files, is there a way to avoid this ? to request the js files just once ?

Comment: @JaredSmith The singleton is only for the frontend, meaning for the specific user ( request ). I'm trying to figure out how I make some data global to all the pages that the specific user requests from the server.

Comment: "But when a user being redirected, seems like the model.js being imported all over again from the backend side" yes, that's how the web works. If you want data to persist across page changes you have to use the local client-side APIs for that like `localStorage` or `indexedDB`. Even if you were doing a SPA you'd want that because when users leave the page and come back they expect to still be logged in.

Comment: This is easily solvable with state management systems for single-page applications, but since you're not using React or other frameworks, the easiest option is to create a custom local storage state manager, which sounds advanced, but is really simple in practice.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk Do you have an example of doing that ?

Comment: @Wahalez [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) lets you store strings that persist across page refreshes. You just JSON serialize the app state you want in there, store it, and then run a check on page load to see if there's previous state stored to be pulled and deserialized. If you google "store user state in localstorage example" you should get plenty of hits.

Comment: @JaredSmith Is it possible to store the model object ? I've looked into it and saw answers that I should use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, but when I print the object to the console, I cannot see the functions that the object should have. Could you assist please ?

Comment: @Wahalez functions are not JSON serializable. You will need to store/load the **state** that you want with localStorage. What you do with it after you've parsed it (like wrapping it in a class instance) is up to you. But you can't put anything in localStorage that you couldn't e.g. send over the wire to/from your server with HTTP.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for making this clear, I was so confused about all this. Will look into it, thank you !!

Comment: A JavaScript object is a singleton. You don't need that nonsense. Just return the "instance" object from the IIFE.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The problem comes when I'm serving the pages from the backend. Everytime I serve a new html page, it refreshes everything in frontend and "links" the js files all over again, causing the data stores in the "singleton" to be wiped out. Managed to fix that using `localStorage`

Comment: I understand that. I was trying to clarify. That it could be a Singleton is mostly irrelevant. What you're talking about is persisting data.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out thanks to [@Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith)

I used [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to save the model's current state and load it back when redirecting to another page.

```js
const Model = (function () {

    let instance;

    let data = {
        isLogged: false,
    };

    function init_localStorage() {
        save_localStorage();
    }

    function load_localStorage() {
        let model = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Model'));
        if (Object.keys(model).length === 0) {
            init_localStorage();
        }

        data = model;
    }

    function save_localStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem('Model', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    function init() {
        load_localStorage();

        return {
            getIsLogged: function () {
                return data.isLogged;
            },
            setIsLogged: function (l) {
                data.isLogged = l;
            },

            saveData: function () {
                save_localStorage();
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (! instance) {
                instance = init();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
})();
```

Eventually, I have two main function: `save...` and `load...` which reads\saves from the localStorage object.
As Jared stated in the comments, JSON cannot stringify a function, thus I created an object called `data` where I store all the model's data ( for example `isLogged` variable ).

Now, whenever I want to access the model's data, I get its instance first: `let model = Model.getInstance();`
and then I can access the methods from the `init` function that I'm returning.
When I request the Model instance, it first checks if the current instance is not yet initialized. If not, it calls the `load_localStorage` which reads localStorage and saves it to `data` variable.

Before I redirect to another page I call `saveData` of Model's instance to save the data object to localStorage, so the page redirected to can read the previous saved state.

In HTML files, I included the js files like this: `<script src="./../model/model.js"></script>`.

I'm sure there is a better solution to the problem, and maybe a more readable code, but this got me working just fine :)

**Edit:**

It is important to note that [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) might be a better solution than [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as localStorage doesn't doesn't expire, meaning if you save things you want to be refreshed \ wiped out when the server is refreshed\updated, it will still load old data from localStorage as nothing changed.

For example, I saved some common HTML part in the model in localStorage, and each time I ran `npm start` it didn't show the changes I made to it, as I'm loading the HTML part from `localStorage` and not again from the server.